# Not Seeing Id In Sails JS Response

Tags: sails.js

So I'm messing around with SailsJS to try to get an API up and running real fast.  I haven't setup a data store yet (will probably use mongodb) but I saw that there is what I'm assuming is like a SQLite database or something.  So I generated a model and controller for a User.  So in the browser I hit user/create.  I see createdAt and updatedAt but no Id.  Do I need a real datastore to see an ID? Is this still something you get for free?

Adapter

```
// Configure installed adapters
// If you define an attribute in your model definition, 
// it will override anything from this global config.
module.exports.adapters = {

    // If you leave the adapter config unspecified 
    // in a model definition, 'default' will be used.
    'default': 'disk',

    // In-memory adapter for DEVELOPMENT ONLY
    // (data is NOT preserved when the server shuts down)
    memory: {
        module: 'sails-dirty',
        inMemory: true
    },

    // Persistent adapter for DEVELOPMENT ONLY
    // (data IS preserved when the server shuts down)
    // PLEASE NOTE: disk adapter not compatible with node v0.10.0 currently 
    //              because of limitations in node-dirty
    //              See https://github.com/felixge/node-dirty/issues/34
    disk: {
        module: 'sails-dirty',
        filePath: './.tmp/dirty.db',
        inMemory: false
    },

    // MySQL is the world's most popular relational database.
    // Learn more: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL
    mysql: {
        module      : 'sails-mysql',
        host        : 'YOUR_MYSQL_SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS',
        user        : 'YOUR_MYSQL_USER',
        password    : 'YOUR_MYSQL_PASSWORD',
        database    : 'YOUR_MYSQL_DB'
    }
};
```

Model

```
/*---------------------
    :: User
    -> model
---------------------*/
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        firstName: 'STRING',
        lastName: 'STRING'
    }

};
```

Comment: Try adding this to your model. `autoPk: true,`

Answer (score 0):

Do `.../user/findAll` to list all the users. Each user should have an 'id' property, e.g.

```
{
   "username":"admin",
   "password":"$2a$10$SP/hWtlJINkMgkAuAc9bxO1iWsvVcglwEU4ctGCiYpx.7ykaFWt56",
   "createdAt":"2013-07-12T17:36:29.852Z",
   "updatedAt":"2013-07-12T17:36:29.852Z",
   "id":1
}
```

Comment: Not seeing it. Below is all I see.

`[{"firstName":"Chad","createdAt":"2013-07-12T04:13:16.917Z","updatedAt":"2013-07-12T04:13:16.917Z"},{"firstName":"Chad","lastName":"Hietala","createdAt":"2013-07-12T04:13:33.538Z","updatedAt":"2013-07-12T04:13:33.538Z"},{"createdAt":"2013-07-12T04:15:44.243Z","updatedAt":"2013-07-12T04:15:44.243Z"},{"createdAt":"2013-07-12T04:15:47.704Z","updatedAt":"2013-07-12T04:15:47.704Z"},{"createdAt":"2013-07-12T04:16:15.506Z","updatedAt":"2013-07-12T04:16:15.506Z"}]`

Comment: /config/adapters.js configures the DB used. I get an 'id' property with both 'default:"disk"' and 'default:"memory"'. Can you post your /config/adapters.js and /api/models.User.js?

Comment: Also: does .../user/find/1 show you the first user? Try it with a few more.

Comment: Updated my post with the files.  I get a `Not Found` meesage when I try to look up a specific user using an id.

Comment: I have the same adapter.js and user.js is fine. I'm using the latest release version of sails 0.8.94 (appears under the boat on lift). Are you perhaps using a 0.9 dev version?

Comment: Yea using the same version as well.

Comment: I'll look at your project if you put in on github.

Answer (score 0):

they removes findAll you can simply use find instad

u can also request like this http://example.de/Model/create?firstname=Foo&lastname=bar

Answer (score 0):

I have checkout this by switching between different DB in a same sails application and its working absolutely fine.

So In this case you can add a property of autoPK to your model and setting it to true like following:

```
module.exports = {
    attribute:{
       //your model attributes with validations.
    },
    autoPK:true
}
```

If this doesn't works for you then I think there is something wrong with your copy of sails you installed on your system.

Please try to install the newer version (v0.9.8) of sails using npm or try to update your package.json with newer version (v0.9.8) details and excute npm install.